# What can I do about a misleading answer with high votes?

Tags: discussion

The answer I am talking about is [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17541235/752842).
I don't feel I have enough evidence to flag this answers so it gets removed, however it is wrong, but seems useful and that is why it has a lot of up-votes.

At first sight I thought it was good, however when he said the Functions can not accept exceptions, I found it weird, but since I don't know so much about Oracle I thought he was right.

Then I read the answers' comments and notice Jon Heller pointed out errors on it.
I normally read the comments, but not everyone does.

For me the information conveyed in that question is for SQL Server.
There can be doubts about the Table itself, but when he categorizes the User Defined Functions, he uses the categories commonly used for SQL Server. As you can see [here](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa175085(v=sql.80).aspx).

I haven't seen User defined functions categorized in that way. Specially the last category is not a term used in Oracle, as you can see [here](https://community.oracle.com/thread/702132).

I would like to point out that this question is one of the top hits in Google when searching about "functions vs procedures in oracle".

I realize this is a bit of a subjective case, since the poster didn't identify his source of information, so, what can I do to get this question removed?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

So, that *particular* answer was shamelessly stolen from this article: https://codingauthority.wordpress.com/2013/03/24/stored-procedures-vs-functions/ - the author didn't even bother copying the text, he just took a screenshot of the table. So I'm deleting it *right now* for that reason. Note that this is something of a classic interview question, and portions of that answer can be found all over the 'Net in various forms.

*In general*, feel free to correct misinformation when you see it. In particular, if it appears that the author just made an inadvertent mistake, go ahead and edit to correct the error (include sources to back up your correction).

If it appears that the author *intended* to convey the misinformation that they did, then write an alternate answer that calls out the error and corrects it. Then downvote the misinformed answer.

Comment: I was sure he had copied from some other place, I just couldn't find it. I found a ton of comparisons, but never that exact one. I was sure about what to do, because it was obvious Jon Heller had tried to do something about it, but the post remained there. And having the actual site, yes that answer was for SQL Server! Thanks a lot Shog9!

Comment: @Dzyann Thank you for asking this question, and Shog9 thank you for taking the time to find the plagiarism.  This was the worst best answer I've seen, I'm glad it's gone.  The user should have taken me up on my 500 point bounty offer when he had the chance!

Comment: @JonHeller I believe he didn't lose the reputation he earned, but It would have been good if he deleted to spare people from reading it.

Comment: _In general, feel free to correct misinformation when you see it._ This could be done in multiple ways: an edit, a comment, a downvote, or (in the case of a moderator) a deletion. Any thoughts on when deletion might be too heavy-handed?

Comment: Moderators will *rarely if ever* delete an answer simply because it is incorrect, @J.R. - that's something the community is expected (and empowered) to handle.